# Actions on Google Simulator fail to refresh

Tags: actions-on-google, actionbuilder

I've built an action using Action Builder in 2 languages, it and en. Opening the simulator I've got the message: `Scenes in locale en differ from scene in locale it`. Opening the console I have a generic error with errorCode 3. Someone had the same problem?

Comment: did you translate all the scenes in EN into IT? or you created different scenes for both languages?

Comment: I have fixed it. Sometimes the AoG builder fails to load the scenes and I need to reopen all. the scenes and "simulate" the change of the phrases. Often happen if you do access simultaneously on the console even if you use 2 different accounts.